# Truncate highest bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please consider the following

```
library(ggplot)
data <- data.frame(qnt=c(10,20,22,12,14,9,1000),lbl=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=lbl, y=qnt)) + geom_histogram(stat="identity")
```

which produces

[image]

Which options should I consider to truncate the highest bar `G` in the plot? (of course explaining to the viewer what I did)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to fiddle with it, you can use the `gridExtra` package, and plot 2 (or more) trimmed out sections of the graph. I've tinkered with the margins to make it line up, but a better plan would probably be to format the axis labels to the same text width,

[image]

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)
data <- data.frame(qnt=c(10,20,22,12,14,9,1000),lbl=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))

g1<-ggplot(data=data, aes(x=lbl, y=qnt)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat="identity")+  
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-10,50)) + 
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)+
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(2,2,6,3),"mm")) 


g2<-ggplot(data=data, aes(x=lbl, y=qnt)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat="identity") +  
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(990,1010)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) + 
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(5,2,0,0),"mm")) 

grid.arrange(g2,g1, heights=c(1/4, 3/4), ncol=1, nrow=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coord_cartesian()` and change limits for the y axis - `coord_cartesian()` will "zoom" the plot to the limits you will provide. Also I used `geom_bar()` as your are plotting factors on x axis.

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=lbl, y=qnt)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))
```

Another possibility is to use logarithm scale for y values.

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=lbl, y=qnt)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_y_log10()
```

Comment: Is `coord_cartesian()` not compatible with `coord_flip()`? They don't seem to work together...

Comment: If you need flip axis then use +coord_flip(ylim=c(0,100))